# VueJS @click pass data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue-google-maps and try to draw polygons on my map. On that point, I'm ok, but I want to get the lat and lng position on the map of my click. When I do this

```
<GmapPolygon v-for="cabstand in cabstands" :path="cabstand.positions" @click="getCabstandClick"/>
```

and in my method

```
getCabstandClick(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

I can get an object with the lat & lng position, but I have to trigger 2 methods, so I use something like this

```
<GmapPolygon v-for="cabstand in cabstands" :path="cabstand.positions" @click="getCabstandClick ; getCabstandInfos(cabstand)"/>
```

And I have no logs in my console, as if it doesn't execute my first method anymore. I tried with a **;** between my two methods, with **&&** or **,** but that's always the same.

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Call a single method on click that calls both methods:

```
<GmapPolygon v-for="cabstand in cabstands" :path="cabstand.positions" @click="callBothMethods(cabstand)"/>

methods: {
    callBothMethods(cabstand) {
        this.getCabstandClick();
        this.getCabstandInfos(cabstand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's logging 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found the solution: I used **$event** variable in my method.

```
<GmapPolygon v-for="cabstand in cabstands" :path="cabstand.positions" @click="getCabstandInfos(cabstand, $event)"/>
```

Thanks for your help.